# Original What Am I

Tags: riddle

These five things describe me:

1. Quintessential to freight
2. Up there
3. Eighteen rubber circles
4. Everyone knows me
5. Need considerable distance to stop

What am I?

Hint 1:

> I am a vehicle

Hint 2:

> The "QUEEN" part is another hint and is significant to the answer.

Hint 3:

> If I had "asked" this question in another particular SE community, they would know the answer right away.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're probably

> Boeing 747

because

- the OP appears to be an active user of

  > [Aviation](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/)
- according to Wikipedia you're sometimes referred to as

  > Queen of the Skies
- you have 18

  > wheels

Comment: Gah, you won first post as I was taking time to add detail.

Answer (score 3):

You are a

> [Boeing 747 jetliner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_747)

Because...

> 1. **Quintessential to freight** - FedEx has their own fleet!
>  2. **Up there** - Up in the air
>  3. **Eighteen rubber circles** - Landing gear has 18 wheels
>  4. **Everyone knows me** - Ask an amateur about a plane model, they will likely say "747"
>  5. **Need considerable distance to stop** - Like, a whole airstrip worth of space!

Bonus: Also known as...

> *The Queen of the Skies*

Bonus 2: There is...

> An [Aviation SE](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: For #1 FedEx used to have a fleet. But that is not that much of a matter.

Comment: I'm from around Indianapolis.  Driving to the *-ahem-* transportation hub of said vehicle, you can see tons of them.

Comment: Hmm, you might be confusing them with the MD-11 or DC-10. The one that FedEx had are already out of the fleet for some years.

Comment: *-shrug-* I am one of said amateurs, so I'm just going by sight. +1 to point #4.

Answer (score 0):

2 answers seem possible, either:

> crown or royal 18 wheelers

another possibility is:

> bicycle

because:

> people deliver things on bikes... Queen song... another SE is on bicycles... etc... but 18 circles doesnt quite fit.

Comment: Yes, that is very significant. If you know what that means in the context of this, you might get it.

Comment: the royal bigrig